# paragraph tag not closed?

Tags: html, firefox, intellij-idea

I simplified my html code down to this

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<div class="index-div">
    <p id="whoarewe">
        <h2>Who are we?</h2>
        wersfgse
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I run it and open up the page source, it says "No p element in scope but a p end tag seen". It runs fine but for some strange reason, Intellij Idea and Firefox both show it as an unnecessary /p tag. Is my computer glitching out?

Edit: Chrome says it's ok
[image: see look]

Comment: "Chrome says it's ok" Oh god my sides

Comment: You really shouldn't nest a header inside a paragraph, not sure if that's the reason you're getting the error but try moving the h2 outside of the p tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a fixed set of elements, belonging to [Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) category, that can be children of `<p>` element:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that
>   mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing
>   content form paragraphs.
>
> ```
> a abbr area (if it is a descendant of a map element) audio b bdi bdo br button 
> canvas cite code data datalist del dfn em embed i iframe img input ins
> kbd keygen label map mark math meter noscript object output 
> progress q ruby s samp script select small span strong sub sup svg
> template textarea time u var video wbr Text
> ```

`<h2>` element, as many other block-level ones, doesn't belong here. In this case, `<p>` element closes automatically. Quoting [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element):

> A p element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately
>   followed by an `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`,
>   `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`, `main`, `nav`,
>   `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or `ul`, element, or if there is no more
>   content in the parent element and the parent element is not an a
>   element.

In this particular case, the structure of DOM is as follows:

```
<p id="whoarewe"></p>
<h2>Who are we?</h2>
wersfgse
</p>
```

... and, as you can see, the end tag isn't really welcome. Actually, you should be grateful for Firefox DOM Inspector marking this error. )

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of that error message is that the `p#whoarewe` element was already implicitly closed when the HTML processor encountered the `h2` element, so the `</p>` end tag at that particular point seems gratuitous because there is no open `p` element for the end tag to close.

So no, your computer is not glitching out. The markup is indeed malformed.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, `#whoarewe` looks like it should be its own `div` element or a sectioning element, rather than a `p`. A paragraph cannot contain a heading; they are two thematically separate structures and cannot exist within the other.